# Scope for information security in 2yrs down the lane?

Tags: firewalls

I'm a fresher. Very recently I started doing Java course because of the wide opportunities we get to enter into an IT industry.

Now, I've got an opportunity to work for a project that's related to information security. Now I'm in dilemma whether to complete my course which would take another 2months of time or grab this opportunity and launch my career through the project at HP.??

Comment: Welcome. That is an [off-topic](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question here. We do not deal with such subjects.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a job in infosec working with a company like HP is a big opportunity. HP are about to split into two organisations, HP ink and Hewlett Packard Enterprise (HPE). HPE are making a massive push into security and want to be taking on the likes of Dell SecureWorks and Deloitte in the next few years, so as far as security goes they are a good company to be with right now.

Really you need to ask yourself is, will completing the course will help you get a better job? Another question you should ask is, are you able and competent do the job without any further education? I had a similar dilemma myself recently, I had to choose between a job in infosec and a PhD...I picked the job.